# Render modal on a route with the parent route rendered in background

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using ReachUI `Dialog` to render a Dialog (Modal).
The `Dialog` is routable at the route `products/create/`, as you can see in the code below.

Is it possible to render both the `ProductsTable` (which is located at the parent route `products/`) and the `Dialog`, when I route to `products/create` so that I can see the `ProductsTable` component in the background of the modal?
I'm hoping to achieve this with `react-router`.

This is what the code looks like now:

```
...
import { Switch, Route, useRouteMatch, match, useHistory, } from "react-router-dom";
import { Dialog } from "@reach/dialog";

export function ProductsPage() {
  const { url }: match = useRouteMatch();
  const { push } = useHistory();

  const gotToCreateProduct = () => push(`${url}/create`);

  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={url}>
          <Page title="Products" onCreateButtonClick={gotToCreateProduct}>
            <ProductsTable></ProductsTable>
          </Page>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${url}/create`}>
            <Dialog isOpen={true} onDismiss={() => push(url)}>
                <ProductForm></ProductForm>
            </Dialog>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out myself,
basically you just have to put 2 `Switch` components next to each other, and remove the `exact` attribute of the parent `Route`.
This way, both `Switch`es will have a match and render their routes.
Makes sense & it works.

```
    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={url}>
                    <Page title="Products" onCreateButtonClick={gotToCreateProduct}>
                        <ProductsTable></ProductsTable>
                    </Page>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`${url}/create`}>
                    <Dialog show={true} title={'Create product'}
                            onClose={() => push(url)}><CreateProduct></CreateProduct></Dialog>
                </Route>
                <Route path={`${url}/:productId/edit`}>
                    <Dialog show={true} title={'Edit product'} onClose={() => push(url)}><EditProduct></EditProduct></Dialog>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

## React router v6

You'll have to use an Outlet in your nested component;

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}>
         <Route path="modal" element={<Modal />} />
      </Route>
   </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And inside the Home component add an Outlet;

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Home(){
   return(
      <>
         Home Code is here
         <Outlet />
      </>
   )
}
```

so now, whenever that route `/home/modal` is opened, it'll open the modal by default. Make sure to keep the prop `isOpen` true by default as the rendering will be controlled by the react router now.

Comment: Shouldn't the Outlet component go inside the Home component instead of Modal?

Answer (score 5):

[@Akshay K Nair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7481663/akshay-k-nair)'s answer is almost perfect, just wrong position of `<Outlet />`. The correct use of `<Outlet />` is to have the parent router component render it (*read more [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet)*). Check out this React Router Dom v6 example:

#### Router

```js
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/:id",
        element: (
          <ModalRoute>
            <Detail />
          </ModalRoute>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

#### Parent Component

```js
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      Insert parent code
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```

#### Modal Route

```js
const ModalRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false)
  const location = useLocation()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = location.pathname.split("/")[1]
    if (id) {
      setOpened(true)
    }
  }, [location.pathname])

  const handleClose = () => {
    navigate("/")
    setOpened(false)
  }

  return (
    <Modal opened={opened} onClose={handleClose}>
        {children}
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and the example using createBrowserRouter was ideal for my situation. It took me 5 minutes to convert a page into a modal dialog on the page that linked to it thanks to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

by changing your first route to

```
<Route path={`${url}*`}>
  <Page title="Products" onCreateButtonClick={gotToCreateProduct}>
    <ProductsTable></ProductsTable>
  </Page>
</Route>
```

your component will be displayed for every route that starts with url
and by removing the Switch component you will be able to match multiple routes

Comment: Then my modal isn't rendered at all

Comment: oh yes it's because of the switch it only allows one route

Answer (score -1):

This should be a start: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/modal-gallery

They conditionally render it as a modal only when you navigate to it from the parent. You can modify it so it always renders as a modal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a great example, only the router isn't routable, which is kind of my goal.

Comment: This wont work in react router v6